# In node.js, the IP address keeps changing. But I thought local computer IP addresses were constant

Tags: node.js, ip, ip-address

I just need to know the user based on their computer instead of using user registration to a database. I thought using the computer's ip address would help with that, but if there is an alternative, I am open to learn about it. Here is the code I am using:

```
const { networkInterfaces } = require('os');

const getLocalIP = () => {
    const nets = networkInterfaces();
    const results = Object.create(null);

    for (const name of Object.keys(nets)) {
        for (const net of nets[name]) {
            if (net.family === 'IPv4' && !net.internal) {
                if (!results[name]) {
                    results[name] = [];
                }
    
                results[name].push(net.address);
                return net.address
            }
        }
    }
}

exports.getLocalIP = getLocalIP
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?  Getting an IP address of a networkInterface has nothing at all to do with keeping track of separate users from a server.  And, you cannot count on a given user always having the same IP address anyway for all sorts of reasons (dynamically assigned home IP addresses, corporate or government proxies, VPNs, etc...).  Ultimately, you probably want a login system to identify what user is connecting to your service as that is portable across any device and any type of network (that's why it's what Google, Facebook, etc... all use).

Comment: For short term identification of a given user in a browser (without login) from a fixed endpoint, you can sometimes use a cookie.